# Google Spreadsheets API: 'SpreadsheetsClient' object has no attribute 'update_cell'

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-drive-api

For some reason, when I'm trying to update one cell using the Google Spreadsheets API in Python, like so:

```
import gdata.spreadsheets.client 
import gdata.gauth

gd_client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
gd_client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)

wksht_id = od6

gd_client.update_cell(spreadsheet_k, wksht_id, 3, 17, 'TEST')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SpreadsheetsClient' object has no attribute 'update_cell'
```

Even though in the source code for client.py, update_cell is very clearly a method for the SpreadsheetsClient class: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/spreadsheets/client.py

This cell has something in it, if that makes any difference. But that's not where the error is coming from. I just have no idea why this isn't working. Maybe something to do with different versions of the API?

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out the source code was updated with the update_cell method but the gdata downloads were never given this method for some reason. You have to go to the source code and copy the method over to your own copy of gdata, or use this workaround: https://gist.github.com/egor83/4634422